# Why is this recursion example giving me an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

This is driving me insane.
Here is the code :

```
function laugh(){
  let counter = 10; 
  if(counter <= 0){
    return;
  } 
  else{
    console.log('laugh'); 
    counter--; 
    laugh()
  }
}
```

Why is this giving me an infinite loop when it's supposed to print 'laugh' 10 times?

Comment: You should define `counter` outside of the function. in this way its always 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like other answers said, each `laugh()` created a new local counter.

The most appropriate recursive method here is to pass the counter as an argument:

```js
function laugh(counter){
  if(counter <= 0){
    return;
  } 
  else{
    console.log('laugh'); 
    laugh(counter - 1) // subtract 1 from the counter and recur
  }
}

laugh(10)
```

This is a pure function approach, reducing the reliance on global vars which can be affected by other functions. It's generally a safer way to program than to use global variables when you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined counter inside the function, so it will be reset to 10 every time the function is called.

```js
let counter = 10; 
function laugh(){
  if(counter <= 0){
    return;
  } 
  else{
    console.log('laugh'); 
    counter--; 
    laugh();
  }
}
laugh();
```

Answer (score 1):

a variable `counter` should be a global variable. At this moment, whenever the function is called, then `counter` will always be declared and initialized by 10.